# Is there a Noether's theorem for approximate conservation and approximate symmetries?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, conservation-laws, approximations, noethers-theorem

It is my impression that verifying a symmetry in physical laws often takes the form of verifying the corresponding conservation law instead. But since experimental verification must allow for quantitative errors, I see three possibilities:

1. There is a version of Noether's theorem that says an *approximate* symmetry corresponds to an *approximate* conservation law, ideally with quantitative bounds on the approximations.
2. A sort of Occam's razor argument: as long as the experimental results are consistent with the conservation law holding *exactly*, we might as well assume it does. Of course if the experiment is inconsistent with the conservation law then it is inconsistent with the symmetry.
3. Symmetries cannot be (and are not) tested by testing the corresponding conservation laws, in the sense that obtaining results consistent with the conservation law tells us nothing about the symmetry.

The difference between 2 and 3 is maybe just a matter of perspective, but I am curious about 1. Phrased differently, if we improve experiments to test conservation laws to a greater accuracy, does that also improve how accurately we know the corresponding symmetry holds?

For background, I am a mathematician, and not intimately familiar with Noether's theorem to begin with. This question is just curiosity that was not answered by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem). I did find [Govinder-Heil-Uzer](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0375-9601(98)00067-X) and related papers but did not manage to verify whether their statement is what I'm wondering about.

Comment: 2) is simply the ordinary definition of physics as the art of approximation. We do it all the time for all scenarios, not just for conservation laws. Symmetries are being tested by their consequences. We do this in all kinds of physics all the time, see e.g. the determination of crystallographic point groups by their optical properties. Homogeneity of space can be tested trivially by momentum conservation etc.. Not sure what you are asking.

Comment: I believe that, assuming an experiment is consistent with our hypothesis, we care about how much of an error it allows for. To put it crudely, I'm asking if the error bars can be transferred via Noether's theorem or if it's only a binary yes/no thing.

Comment: If there is a symmetry breaking mechanism, then it can usually be written as a Hamiltonian, a thermodynamic relationship, a geometric distortion etc., so yes, it can be characterized. However, a symmetry is a binary relationship. Either it exists or it doesn't.

Comment: @FlatterMann In the same way that a real number is either zero or non-zero. You can certainly quantify if a group action is *close to the identity*, at least in some cases (it seems sufficient for the group to be compact). But your objection seems to be more fundamental so perhaps I am confused about something.

Comment: And that is completely enough in physics. Physics is not philosophical absolutism. It's the art of approximation. Energy conservation is a perfectly fine local symmetry. It doesn't hold for the entire universe. We are working with both scenarios.

Comment: @FlatterMann if you're saying that physics only cares whether an experiment refutes a theory and not the margin of error it allows for then that is surprising to me. Or maybe you have an a priori reason why symmetries should be treated differently than conservation laws in this respect. Or something else that I've not understood. In any case, maybe you could elaborate in an answer instead of continuing in comments?

Comment: Symmetries and conservation laws are the same thing. That's Noether's theorem. Theories are only valid within their application domain. Newton is entirely false (both experimentally and theoretically) but if "all" you want is to build a dump truck or fly a spacecraft to Mars, then it's a great tool to have.